# Adjust page size in ReactToPrint

Tags: javascript, reactjs, printing

I am using [ReactToPrint](https://github.com/gregnb/react-to-print) library to print a section of my page using React.js.

```html
<ReactToPrint
  trigger={() => (
    <Button
      variant="contained"
      color="primary"
      className={classes.button}
    >
      PRINT &nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;
      <PrintIcon
        className={classNames(classes.leftIcon, classes.iconSmall)}
      />
    </Button>
  )}
  content={() => this.componentRef}
/>
<Barcode
  ref={el => (this.componentRef = el)} 
  name={this.state.displayValue}
  value={this.state.barcodeValue}
  text={this.state.displayValue}
  fontSize={20}
  width={2}
/>
```

I can see `pageStyle` property in the GitHub documentation but I cannot find how to use it. Can someone please help me set the size to something like 2.5 x 4 inches?

Answer (score 4):

Not sure if you're still having this issue, but try

```
pageStyle="@page { size: 2.5in 4in }"
```

within your `ReactToPrint`.
This would adjust your print template page size.

Comment: It worked, thanks, brother. 

Comment: Would you recommend the same approach for someone who wants to use a thermal printer?

Answer (score 0):

```
export function styledPdf() {
  const pageStyle = `{ size: 2.5in 4in }`;
  const divPrint = React.useRef(null);

  return (
    <Div ref={divPrint}>
      <ReactToPrint
        pageStyle={pageStyle}
        trigger={() => <button>Print this out!</button>}
        content={() => divPrint.current}
      />
    </Div>
  );
}
```

Comment: Not working.
I tried A5, A6 sizes in inches and none worked.

Answer (score 0):

if `pageStyle` prop of `react-to-print` isn't working properly you can try this.

```
  const pageStyle ="
  @page {
    size: A4 landscape;
  }
";
```

and add to style tag

```
 <div id="item-detail-print">
    <style>{pageStyle}</style>
      <Barcode
       value={data?.itemById.barCode}
       ref={componentRef}  />
 </div>
```

Comment: can i give width and height (in pixels) to page size ? I know beforehand the dimensions (in pixels) of the content to be printed.

Comment: Yes, you can here is the reference.
[www.smashingmagazine.com](https://www.smashingmagazine.com/2015/01/designing-for-print-with-css/)

Comment: Thanks for the reference, I've managed to set it dynamically with template literals (See my answer below). However, page size is correctly set ONLY when its square (e.g 1200x1200 (dimensions of the image that is being utilized to set the page size)). I'm setting the size of the page based on the image uploaded by the user because I'm printing images uploaded by the user. So page dimensions should be equal to image dimensions. Experienced such problem before ?

Answer (score 0):

this has worked for me.

```
 const handlePrint = useReactToPrint({
    pageStyle: `@media print {
      @page {
        size: 500mm 500mm;
        margin: 0;
      }
    }`,
    {...}
  });
```

Setting it dynamically w/ template literals

```
const [dimensions, setDimensions] = React.useState({ width: 500, height: 500 });

pageStyle: `@media print {
      @page {
        size: ${dimensions.width}px ${dimensions.height}px;
        margin: 0;
      }
    }`,
```

w/ useReactToPrint

```
const [dimensions, setDimensions] = React.useState({ width: 500, height: 500 });


const handlePrint = useReactToPrint({
  pageStyle: `@media print {
      @page {
        size: ${dimensions.width}mm ${dimensions.height}mm;
        margin: 0;
      }
    }`,
  content: () => componentRef.current,
  onAfterPrint: () => handleResetPrint()
});
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use it this way, which is also what is recommended by [`react-to-print`](https://www.npmjs.com/package/react-to-print) on npm.

1. Here the default page size is A4.
2. **Issue**: *most browsers do not allow JavaScript or CSS to set the page size*

```js
@media all {
  .page -
    break {
      display: none;
    }
}

@media print {
  html,
  body {
    height: initial!important;
    overflow: initial!important; -
    webkit - print - color - adjust: exact;
  }
}

@media print {
  .page -
    break {
      margin - top: 1 rem;
      display: block;
      page -
        break -before: auto;
    }
}

@page {
  size: auto;
  margin: 20 mm;
}
```