# how i adjust page size in react to print library

Tags: reactjs, react-to-print

i am using react to print library in one of my react js functional component. i want to adjust the page size according to my need. for one component i need to adjust my page size to a4 for printing and for other i want to adjust my page size to legal
here is my react to print hook

```
 const componentRef = useRef();

    const handlePrint = useReactToPrint({
        content: () => componentRef.current
    });
```

and here i am using it to print my component

```
<div className="print-only position-relative" ref={componentRef} style={{width: "20.6cm", height: "32.91cm"}}>
my html structure to print
</div>
```

i have tried many solutions like i am highlighting below

```
 const handlePrint = useReactToPrint({
        content: () => componentRef.current,
        pageStyle: '{ size: 2.5in 4in }'
    });
```

using external css file like this

```
.print-only {
    display: none;
}

@media print {
    @page {
        size: A5;
    }

    .print-only {
        display: block;
    }
}
```

but not succeeded to set the page size

i also tried all solution mention over stack overflow link [adjust-page-size-in-reacttoprint](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/54898951/adjust-page-size-in-reacttoprint)

[how to set A5 page size in react-to-print](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/65631549/how-to-set-a5-page-size-in-react-to-print)

but again got failure
is there anyone to solve this problem
Note: my chrome version is 122 which is supported according to [caniuse](https://caniuse.com/mdn-css_at-rules_page_size)

Comment: I have been trying this. It's strange: Chrome seems to _show_ the right page size in the preview window, but it doesn't set the correct size in the paper options

Comment: I did some testing using a basic HTML page and using normal printing, _not_ `react-to-print`. It still does NOT work in Chrome. I think this is an issue with Chrome, not with `react-to-print`. Tested using: `<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
    <head>
        <style type="text/css" media="print">
            @page { size: A5; }
        </style>
    </head>
    <body>
        Test
    </body>
</html>`

Comment: I can't get this to work in Safari or Firefox either :(

Comment: yes but
[caniuse](https://caniuse.com/mdn-css_at-rules_page_size)
says chrome latest version support the page property i also tried on other browsers but problem remains same and interestingly it also dose not apply any styles to page using page property

Comment: caniuse is not some sort of official source. It's a good resource, but it can be wrong. I would say we should report the issue to the browsers, but that it's so consistent makes me thing we both may have local printer options that are being set that maybe the browser can't control? Honestly not sure, will require more testing on more devices/browsers

Comment: Yes you are right we should report this issue.